# Build Error for webkitgtk when webkitgtk option is enabled in Buildroot

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, buildroot, webkitgtk

I am running buildroot (2022.02.7) using an Ubuntu VM (22.10, 64 bit).

I enable the midori package and selecting this option also selects webkitgtk (v2.36.7), downloading and configuring of the source runs with no errors.

During the build process, make throws a couple of errors and crashes.

```
[ 45%] Building CXX object Source/WebCore/CMakeFiles/WebCore.dir/__/__/WebCore/DerivedSources/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-3a52ce78-76.cpp.o
make[4]: *** [Source/WebCore/CMakeFiles/WebCore.dir/build.make:4281: Source/WebCore/CMakeFiles/WebCore.dir/__/__/WebCore/DerivedSources/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-3a52ce78-31.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1018: Source/WebCore/CMakeFiles/WebCore.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:293: /home/dev/workspace/pios4/output/build/webkitgtk-2.36.7/.stamp_built] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Error 2
```

Scrolling back in the log, this error is reported:

```
[ 45%] Building CXX object Source/WebCore/CMakeFiles/WebCore.dir/__/__/WebCore/DerivedSources/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-3a52ce78-52.cpp.o
In file included from /home/dev/workspace/pios4/output/build/webkitgtk-2.36.7/Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/filters/FESpecularLighting.h:25,
                 from /home/dev/workspace/pios4/output/build/webkitgtk-2.36.7/Source/WebCore/svg/SVGFESpecularLightingElement.h:25,
                 from /home/dev/workspace/pios4/output/build/webkitgtk-2.36.7/WebCore/DerivedSources/JSSVGFESpecularLightingElement.h:26,
                 from /home/dev/workspace/pios4/output/build/webkitgtk-2.36.7/WebCore/DerivedSources/JSDOMWindow.cpp:416,
                 from /home/dev/workspace/pios4/output/build/webkitgtk-2.36.7/WebCore/DerivedSources/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-3a52ce78-31.cpp:2:
/home/dev/workspace/pios4/output/build/webkitgtk-2.36.7/Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/filters/FELighting.h:72:41: error: ‘LightingData’ does not name a type
   72 |     inline void platformApplyNeon(const LightingData&, const LightSource::PaintingData&);
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Since I need to keep this current buildroot config for other compatibility items, I tried option 2 from the answer here [Incomplete WEBKITGTK build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744576/incomplete-webkitgtk-build) and the build still fails.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This apparently happens when you try to build webkitgtk on buildroot with the target set to 32bit ARM. You can switch to 64bit (did not test this) or apply this patch: https://patchwork.yoctoproject.org/project/oe-core/patch/20220908021846.2245323-1-raj.khem@gmail.com/

The patch worked for me.